# Check if process is running

Tags: linux, bash, process, grep

I am trying to check if a process is running. If it is running I want a return value of 'OK' and if not a return value of 'Not OK'. I can only use 'ps' without any other arguments attached (eg. ps -ef) if thats the correct term. The code I have is:

```
if ps | grep file; then  echo 'OK'; else  echo 'NO'; fi
```

The problem with this is that it does not search for the exact process and always returns 'OK', I don't want all the information to appear I just want to know if the file exists or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code always returns 'OK', because grep finds itself in the process list ('grep file' contains the word 'file'). A fix would be to do a `grep -e [f]ile' (-e for regular expression), which doesn't find itself.

Answer (score 8):

Spare `grep` for real problems:

```
ps -C file
```

avoids the problem of using `grep` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps | grep -q '[f]ile'
```

Answer (score 2):

What about "pgrep"?

```
$ pgrep -x foo
xxxx
$
```

where xxxx is the pid of the binary running with the name foo. If foo is not running, then no output.

Also:

> $ if [[ `pgrep -x foo` ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no" ; fi;

will print "yes" if foo is running; "no" if not.

see pgrep man page.

Answer (score 1):

When I know the pid I prefer:

```
[ -d /proc/<pid> ] && echo OK || echo NO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ps | grep file | grep -v grep;
then echo 'ok';
else echo 'no';
```

grep -v grep makes sure that the result you get is not the grep statement in execution.

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution with grep as well:

```
if [ "$(ps aux | grep "what you need" | awk '{print $11}')" == "grep" ]; then
...
elif [ ... ]; then
...
else
...
fi
```

This works fine in Debian 6, not sure about other distros. `'{print $11}'` is needed, because the sytem treats grep as a process as well.